# Multiple INNER JOIN with separated PHP row output

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to output information from three tables and I wanted to find out the best way to be able to output the correct row information when multiple columns are the same.

I have a simple booking database that handles testing on a laptop (please excuse my poor photoshop database)
[image: Database]

Im using the following code to output my rows:

```
$Event_list = $dbconn->query('SELECT *
                                  FROM event_booking
                                  INNER JOIN event_candidate
                                  ON event_booking.candidate_id=event_candidate.id
                                  INNER JOIN event_information
                                  ON event_booking.information_id=event_information.id
                                  INNER JOIN event_machine
                                  ON event_booking.machine_id=event_machine.id
                                  INNER JOIN event_machine_time
                                  ON event_booking.machine_time_id=event_machine_time.id
                                  WHERE information_id = '.$_GET["id"].'');
```

Is there anyway to make separate out the columns when outputting the row? Something like the below; I know that doesn't work, but is something similar possible?

```
$Event_list_row['event_information.id']
```

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: The best way is to explicitly list the columns you want, rather than using `SELECT *`.

Comment: How does that work if I need to select 'id' from multiple tables?

Comment: You need to use column aliases like `SELECT event_booking.id AS event_booking_id ...`

Comment: Will that work for all including the INNER JOIN's i.e `SELECT event_information.id AS event_information_id, event_booking.id AS event_booking_id` etc.

Comment: You can also alias the tables, like event_booking eb, then refer to the id column in event_booking as eb.id.

Comment: @JosephGregory - Yes - just try it.

Comment: Yeah I have now and it works perfectly thanks